# Xcode: how to do linear animation in a CATransaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation

My transaction starts slow, gets fast, then goes slow.
I need linear speed throughout.

I've found `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` but can't find an example of `[CATransaction begin]`

Here is my code:

```
[ CATransaction begin ]; 
    if( graph_animation_enable )
        [CATransaction setAnimationDuration: graph_animation_seconds ];
    else
        [CATransaction setAnimationDuration: 0 ];

    //[CATransaction setValue : ( id ) kCFBooleanTrue forKey : kCATransactionDisableActions]; 
    graph_CALayer.frame = CGRectMake( left_x, top_y, width, height );
    graph_CALayer.backgroundColor = bar_background_color.CGColor;

    CAMediaTimingFunction *linearTiming = 
      [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction: linearTiming];

[CATransaction commit];
```

I TRIED THE ANSWER, BUT STILL NON-LINEAR.
Animation starts, but then slows down.

Comment: You must change the transaction's properties **before** you change the layer properties. Also, `frame` is not an animatable property in `CALayer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CATransaction` `setAnimationTimingFunction` and the timing value of `kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear`

The code would look like this:

```
CAMediaTimingFunction *linearTiming = 
  [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction: linearTiming]
```

Comment: I made an error in the first version of the code I posted. Check the edited version, that DOES use `linearTiming`.

Comment: Hmm.  Still not linear:  starts fast then slows.

Comment: Edit your question to show the latest code. (It still needs to be inside a `[CATransaction begin]` and `[CATransaction commit]`.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118369/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-doug-null).

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 5, `CATransaction` has a method called [`setAnimationTimingFunction(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catransaction/1448279-setanimationtimingfunction). `setAnimationTimingFunction(_:)` has the following declaration:

```
class func setAnimationTimingFunction(_ function: CAMediaTimingFunction?)
```

> Sets the timing function used for all animations within this transaction group. [...] This is a convenience method that sets the `CAMediaTimingFunction` for the `value(forKey:)` value of the `kCATransactionAnimationTimingFunction` key.

---

Therefore, you can use one of the following code snippets in order to set a linear animation for your `CATransaction`:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear))
/* ... */
CATransaction.commit()
```

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setValue(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear), forKey: kCATransactionAnimationTimingFunction)
/* ... */
CATransaction.commit()
```